# How do I create a facade class with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, facade

I'm having a little problem with creating a facade model class with Laravel. I have followed http://laravel.com/docs/facades but I guess I'm missing something.

I have created a folder in `app/models` called `foo`. In that folder I have two files.

First file (Foo.php):

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace;

class Foo {
    public function method() {

    }
}
?>
```

Second file (FooFacade.php):

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Foo extends Facade {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'foo'; }
}
?>
```

Then I added `Foo => 'Mynamespace\Foo'` to the `aliases` array in `app/config/app.php` and ran `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Now when I try to run `Foo::method()` I get `Non-static method Mynamespace\Foo::method() should not be called statically`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set the service provider and alias in `config/app.php`. Take in consideration that the alias points to the facade class, not the class itself (it's confusing in the laravel documentation). With that you avoid the non-static error

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### Step 1

Create a folder called `facades` in your `app` folder (`app/facades`).

#### Step 2

Add the facade folder to your composer autoload.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
        "app/facades"
    ]
},
```

#### Step 3

Create a Facade file in that folder (`FooFacade.php`) and add this content:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MyClass extends Facade {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'MyClassAlias'; } // most likely you want MyClass here
}
```

#### Step 4

Create a model in `app/models` (`MyClass.php`).

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;

use Eloquent; // if you're extending Eloquent

class MyClass extends Eloquent {
    ...
}
```

#### Step 5

Create a new service provider (you can create a folder in app called `serviceproviders` and add it to composer autoload) (`app/models/MyClassServiceProvider.php`).

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyClassServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('MyClassAlias', function(){
            return new MyNamespace\MyClass;
        });
    }
}
```

Here you can add new binding if you want another facade (don't forget to create a facade file if so).

#### Step 6

Add the service provider to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

```
'providers' => array(
    ...
    'MyServiceProvider'
)
```

#### Step 7

Run `composer dump` so we can access our new classes.

#### Step 8

You can now access `MyClassAlias::method()` as a facade.

Comment: Awesome! You might want to add `'Foo' => 'FooFacade'` to your aliases in config/app.php

Answer (score 4):

It's well explained in that post: http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create Service provider

```
<?php
    namespace App\Providers;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    class NewFacadeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
       public function register(){
           $this->app->singleton('TestFacades',function() {
            //'TestFacades' alias name for the façade class
               return new \App\TestFacade;
           });
       }
    }
```

Step 2: Create Façade class which extends Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade class.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Facade; //created 'facade' folder in app directory
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
    class TestFacade extends Facade{
        protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { 
            return 'TestFacades'; //'TestFacades' alias name for the façade class declare in the class 'NewFacadeServiceProvider'
        } 
    }
```

Step 3: Create the class(TestFacade.php) where you want to add functions.

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    class TestFacade{
        public function dummy(){
            return "Business Logic ";
        }   
    }
```

Step 4: Register service provider and provide alias name in Config\App.php

```
'providers' => [ //...
     App\Providers\NewFacadeServiceProvider::class
 ],

 //Class Aliases
 'aliases' => [ //...
    'FacadeTester' => App\Facade\TestFacade::class,
 ]
```

Call the function Route.php:

```
Route::get('/skull',function(){
    return FacadeTester::dummy();
});
```

Call function in Controller:

```
return \FacadeTester::dummy();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Laravel 5 methode:

To create a Facade you need 3 components:

- The wanna be Facade Class, the class that needs to become accessible via facade.
- The Facade required Class.
- The Service Provider, which registers the Facade class in the App container

Here's a full example: in the example I'm creating the Facade `ModulesConfig` for the `ModulesConfigReaderService` class.

**1) the service class that needs to become accessible via a facade**

```
<?php

namespace Hello\Services\Configuration\Portals;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class ModulesConfigReaderService
{

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return 'Whatever';
    }

}
```

this is a very normal class

**2) the facade required class**

```
<?php

namespace Hello\Services\Configuration\Facade;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ModulesConfig extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'modulesConfigReaderService';
    }

}
```

simple class extending from the Facade

**3) the service provider**

```
<?php

namespace Hello\Services\Configuration\Providers;

use Hello\Modules\Core\Providers\Abstracts\ServiceProvider;

class ModulesConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('modulesConfigReaderService', function(){
            return $this->app->make('Hello\Services\Configuration\Portals\ModulesConfigReaderService');
        });
    }
}
```

a service provider that binds everything together.

**USAGE:**

1) register the service providers normally

2) access the service class via the facade

```
$whatever = ModulesConfig::getSomething();
```

Comment: How do you **register the service providers normally**