# newly created facade not working in laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a class called Messaging and I created a facade to using it like

```
Messaging::getConversationMessages($conv_id, $user_id);
```

I have followed all the instructions in this link below

[How do I create a facade class with Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957790/how-do-i-create-a-facade-class-with-laravel)

This is my MessagingServiceProvider calss below which does the binding

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MessagingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register() {
    App::bind('messaging', function()
    {
        return new \Messaging\Messaging;
    }
    );
}
```

}

Below is my facade class that I created for me to use it in the way I wanted to

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Messaging extends Facade
{

/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'messaging'; }

}
```

I have placed my MessagingServiceProvider.php inside a folder called serviceproviders inside app folder, and placed the messaging.php(the file containing the facade class) inside a folder called facade in the app folder and added them to auto load.

Below is the model class for the facade

```
<?php
namespace Messaging;

use Eloquent; // if you're extending Eloquent

class Messaging extends Eloquent {
    ...
}
```

After doing all this still I am getting an error "Non-static method Messaging\Messaging::getConversationMessages() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using your Facade. Try to namespace it and use a different name:

```
<?php namespace Messaging;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MessagingFacade extends Facade
{
   ...
}
```

Then you

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And try to use it this way:

```
Messaging\MessagingFacade::getConversationMessages()
```

If it works for you, you create an alias for it in `app/config/app.php`.

```
'Messaging' => 'Messaging\MessagingFacade',
```

And you should be able to use it as:

```
Messaging::getConversationMessages()
```

About namespaced classes, every time you need to a class from another namespace, you need to go root:

```
\DB::whatever();
```

Comment: I think it works fine as now I have a different error "Class 'Messaging\DB' not found" and the code is  as below, but wondering is this because of using the namespace as Messaging??/ <?php 
    namespace Messaging;
 class Messaging extends  \Tzookb\TBMsg\TBMsg {
  
  public function getConversationMessages($conv_id, $user_id) {

        $results = DB::select(
 '
            SELECT msg.id as msgID, msg.content, msg.created_at, us.id as userId, us.username
            FROM messages_status mst
            INNER JOIN messages msg

Comment: sorry I am completely new to this ... any help would be great

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's working you just have to tell PHP that DB is in another namespace using `\DB::method()`