# Laravel 4: Using Facade and Eloquent in same workbench?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, workbench, facade

Suppose I have this `Facade` in one of my module:

```
// workbench/vendor/module1/src/Vendor/Module1/Facades/Module1.php

<?php namespace Vendor\Module1\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Module1 extends Facade {

  /**
   * Get the registered name of the component.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'module1'; }
```

}

And I create an `Eloquent` of the same module, like this:

```
// workbench/vendor/module1/src/models/Module1.php

<?php

class Module1 extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tb_module_1';

}
```

When I'm trying to call `Module1` in my code that was intended to `Eloquent`, ex. `$module1 = new Model1`, it returns a `Facade` instead of `Eloquent` (ex. I can't use $module1->save()).

How to make `Eloquent` and `Facade` works in module development of Laravel? (If there are any suggestion that it is pointless to use both `Eloquent` and `Facade`, I would really love to hear the opinion)

Comment: I don't understand why you're creating a facade with the same name as the model? What's the purpose of the facade? What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: @davidnknight: it is for the same module, is it really pointless to create Facade and Eloquent together (or just Eloquent is enough) for a single module?

Comment: @davidnknight: my point of creating facade is that i am able to use view from each module, so if I name my `Facade` of `Module1` as `module1`, and i have a view in it, i can use the view in other modules like: `@include('module1::myview')` <-- if you got a way for this working in `Eloquent` I would love to hear it

Comment: I really don't understand why you'd want to create a view on the model. The model should do nothing more than represent what the object looks like, including its attributes and relationships, anything else should be moved out to repositories, interfaces and presenters etc.

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to create views for each object but rather than just creating files in your app/views folder, you're for some reason trying to add them via static methods on the model. Am I correct in my understanding? If so, why this way?

Comment: @davidnknight: the accepted answer from here is close to what i want, thanks:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957790/how-do-i-create-a-facade-class-with-laravel