# Use a vendor class from composer in Laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel

How would I go around using this class/library in Laravel:
https://github.com/planetteamspeak/ts3phpframework

I tried to include it in config/app.php providers like this:

```
planetteamspeak\ts3-php-framework\libraries\TeamSpeak3.php::class,
```

But I keep getting this error, and I couldn't find anything about it that helped me. I also tried to add it without .php at the end but that doesn't help either.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in PATH-HERE\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:734
```

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use your class/library in Laravel, first you should put in your composer.json dependecy for that `ts3phpframework`

```
"require": {
"planetteamspeak/ts3phpframework" : "1.*"
}
```

Inside file `app.php` you need to do 2 things (something like this, dunno the proper name of alias and provider (be sure to do composer update before doing it)

First add provider (just a hint how to do it)

```
'providers' => [
ts3phpframework/ts3phpframeworkProvider::class
]
```

Second add alias (just a hint how to do it)

```
'aliases' => [
'ts3phpframework' => ts3phpframework\Facades\ts3phpframework::class,
]
```

If you won't be able to get this library with composer, then add it manually with a [help of this](http://blog.jambura.com/2014/04/26/add-your-own-github-library-in-laravel-using-composer/).  If you won't be able to find alias and provider, then create them manually with a help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957790/how-do-i-create-a-facade-class-with-laravel/19811029#19811029).

And at the end, very similar question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38344851/5139222)

Comment: I already added it to composer.json, it's just when adding it to app.php it fails and gives out the error I mentioned in the OP. Also edited it now to show how I added it to providers.