# How can use vue-admin framework with laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, admin, vue.js

I install vue-admin by npm and now is in node_modules folder.

how can I import it to laravel in app.js file from node_modules.

can I use something like

```
import  { app }  from 'vue-admin/client/app'
```

Comment: Already answered in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38371423/5139222) . Is this you looking for?

Comment: No this is for using class in laravel. what i am looking is to import js framework from node_modules in Vue-js app.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put in your app.js file this like this in your resource folder.

### var VueAdmin= require('vue-admin');

### Vue.use(VueAdmin);

"vue-admin" depends what is the name of the folder or the module you want to include

and then run your gulp or gulp webpack.